# Why Oracle SQL SELECT expression doesn't print decimal value?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, sqlplus

```
select (4*(22/7)*3958.759*3958.759) as "Earth's Area" from dual;

Prints:
Earth's Area
------------
   197016573
```

It should print 197016572.595304. Why the digits after point were ignored in the output?

Comment: Your query should [work fine and prints `197016572.595304`](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d41d8/6540),it seems something else causing that problem

Comment: Works in demo, but not in your environment?

Comment: Yes, it does on SQL Fiddle. Why not on my SQL Plus prompt? Strange! What could be the reason behind?

Comment: try `select (4.0*(22.0/7.0)*3958.759*3958.759) as "Earth's Area" from dual;`

Comment: Still the same output. No digits after '.'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume you are using SQL*PLUS. The reason why you are not seeing the rest of the number is the value of `numwidth` parameter. By default it's 10, so you need to adjust it a little, make it 30 for instance. Here is an example:

```
SQL> select (4*(22/7)*3958.759*3958.759) as "Earth's Area" from dual;

Earth's Area                                                                    
------------                                                                    
   197016573                                                                    

SQL> set numwidth 31

SQL> select (4*(22/7)*3958.759*3958.759) as "Earth's Area" from dual;

 Earth's Area                                                 
----------------                                                 
 197016572.595304
```

Also you can override the value of `numwidth` parameter by either `set numformat` or `column format`

Answer (score 2):

This is SQL*Plus and has nothing to do with what is being returned from the database. You can use SQL*Plus column formatting commands to get the formats you want, like this:-

```
SQL> select (4*(22/7)*3958.759*3958.759) as "Earth's Area" from dual;

Earth's Area
------------
   197016573

SQL> col "Earth's Area" for 99,999,999,999.9999999
SQL> /

           Earth's Area
-----------------------
    197,016,572.5953040
```

The Oracle docs with further details for formatting options are [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B14117_01/server.101/b12170/ch13.htm).

Answer (score 0):

```
to_char((4*(22/7)*3958.759*3958.759)), 'FM99999990D00999999999')
```

The FM removes leading blanks. The 9's represent an optional number in that position. The D represents the decimal separator. The 0's represent mandatory numbers in that position.

Comment: I don't want to use any functions.

Comment: Try select `CAST((4*(22/7)*3958.759*3958.759) AS DOUBLE) as "Earth's Area" from dual;`